# What is the use of this pin in my AC to AC converter

Tags: adapter

I am using a 9V AC converter for a digitech product. But I notice that there is a pin in a socket kind of thing in the adapter. What is the use of this pin?

[image: img 1]

[image: img 2]

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: Could not find the specification for it. This is the product.
http://digitech.com/en/products/ps0913b

Comment: Based on the link you provided, it appears the adapter has a normal cord with a DC plug (but remember, it's an AC adapter; just the plug type is *called* a DC power plug) on the end, so this jack is *in addition* to that cord. I couldn't say if it is some sort of duplicate (wired in parallel) or if it serves some other function, like testing for quality control. You could use a multimeter to check it out.

Comment: @Tanmoy  This input jack on an AC to AC wall wart looks odd.  I think, you have the following options.  (1) Open the case (which may or may not be worth it) and post the picture of the inside of the adapter, or draw a diagram.  (2) Mirror this question of yours at the DigiTech forum.  They have their own community/forum.  Or, e-mail their support.

Comment: Silly me. It is actually written at the back of the adapter ... the main output is 1.3A and the pin output is 0.1A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the center pin of a standard DC Power Jack (also known as a barrel jack).

**Edit:** *Note that this is just the name of the type of connector, so if your adapter is an AC to AC adapter, it still supplies AC.*

The inside of the jack makes contact with the outer contact on the plug, while the pin makes contact with the inside of the plug.

**DC Jack:**

[image: DC Jack]

**DC Plug:**

[image: DC Plug]

They are available in different sizes and diameters. There are lots of related questions you might find useful:

- [How can I tell the size of a barrel power connector?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/59595/2028)
- [Connecting a DC barrel jack to a PCB board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/94775/2028)
- [What to do with third contact in DC barrel plug with only two input contacts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/90529/2028)
- [How to solder wires on to this power barrel plug?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/77671/2028)
- [Electrical part question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/124943/2028) (about DC power jacks)

Comment: Does it mean the same adapter can be used as 9V DC adapter as well?

Comment: @Tanmoy No, the name of these jacks is just typically "DC" but it doesn't mean that they are carrying DC. If your adapter is an AC to AC adapter, then it is supplying AC even though it utilizes a DC jack. Good question.